# How to Update pip in docker using fig?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, docker, fig

It seems like the pip in docker is old:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 351, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2363, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead
```

ive pip 6.1 something on machine but I think thats the old dockers version. and im not sure where to locate it so i can pull and update it.

Comment: also note that now fig is officially deprecated in favor of docker-compose , which does exactly the same job but is directly integrated into recent docker installation.

Answer (score 0):

pip is not a part of docker, but a part of python. Therefore, you must upgrade the pip during the docker image creation, I am not sure how your Dockerfile looks but something along these lines need to be added to your docker file:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qqy python-pip
```

If you are not using a Dockerfile, then you will need to use one in order to update pip and or python.